# Add bibtex to a file in Mendeley

Tags: bibtex, metadata

I am using Mendeley. I have a folder with pdf article files and Mendeley uses their metadata to extract citation information (Authors, name, journal title,...).

However, it usually makes mistakes and I have to overwrite the information manually. I would like to know if there is a way to link the bibtext info from the article so the citation information be correct.

Comment: For example, I add the pdf file of this paper: "Detecting Engagement in Egocentric Video" (https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-46454-1_28).   Mendeley has an empty space on "Published In".

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it seems that Mendeley doesn't have a way yet to link a bibtex file to an existing PDF, it only do the opposite, linking a PDF to an existing bibtex file. So it is always better if you first import the bibtex then upload your PDF.

Nevertheless, I tried uploading the bibtex to Mendeley (although I already have the PDF imported and wrongly metadata'ed) so I ended up with two references for the same article, then select (Ctrl+Click) both files in the Central library list, Right-click and choose "Merge Documents", and it worked for me, I've got the old PDF file with the correct imported bibtex info.

The other good think about merging is, it is gonna merge the new file (bibtex) into the old one (PDF), not the opposite, so you don't have to worry if you have already written and referenced in a word document, and corrected the metadata using "merging" later.

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution Mendeley suggests. Here's the process:

> 1. Copy and paste the correct article title from the PDF into the title field in the Details tab
> 2. Right-click (Cmd + click for Macs) on the document in the central library list and select Mark As -> Needs Review
> 3. In the Details tab, click Search by Title which will look for a match in the Mendeley Catalogue (as of Mendeley 1.13).

The "Search by Title" feature has worked most of the time for me. You may want to look through the updated details one last time--I've spotted small mistakes from time to time.

(Originally retrieved from http://support.mendeley.com/customer/en/portal/articles/197284-the-metadata-for-one-of-my-pdfs-has-been-extracted-incorrectly)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Crediting sources is a good practice. The objective of this site is, however, to be self-contained and not rely on external sources that may disappear. Would you mind detailing here the required steps ?

Comment: Sorry about that. Answer has been edited. Is this in line with the guidelines?

Comment: Don't worry! And thank you for providing an answer!

Comment: It works with some papers. But if the article is not in the Mendeley database that means I have to add the info manually?

Comment: @jessica, correct. Mendeley is constantly improving their data extraction process (see the link below), and so you may have to manually add some information sometimes. As a side note, I tried importing the arXiv version of your article and the information seemed to load much better than the link on Springer.  Here's Mendeley's explanation of the data extraction process:  http://support.mendeley.com/customer/en/portal/articles/227883-how-does-the-automatic-document-details-extraction-work-

Comment: one of the best options is lookup of the doi