# Copy BibTex information to Mendeley

Tags: bibtex

sorry, this questions rather refers to a Mendeley import question, but I would be thankful if you could help me anyway. 
Either Mendeley or I am stupid - and I would be thankful if you could convince me that the latter is true!

Mendeley seems to be quite promising, so I decided to change from JabRef to Mendeley. I got my collection of papers in a few folders, and I uploaded them - so far so good. 
Unfortuntely, Mendeley has some issues with some of the older papers and does not get title,etc. right and puts them in the "Need Review" folder.

Using the ["copy+paste title  & search for it"-solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376015/add-bibtex-to-a-file-in-mendeley) doesnt work properly for older papers (which are a few).

I also tried to copy the DOI and to look it up - again without success.

So I think what would be the easiest way (and what I always did with JabRef) is to look up the paper on google scholar, click cite => copy BibTex Code aaaaaand finally => Copy that code to Mendeley.

something like:

`@article{pandalai1965buckling,
  title={Buckling of orthotropic circular plates},
  author={Pandalai, KAV and Patel, Sharad A},
  journal={The Aeronautical Journal},
  volume={69},
  number={652},
  pages={279--280},
  year={1965},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press}
}`

But wait! How!?! I do not see where to import BibTeX-code. 
Isn't there some good old BibTex code window (like in JabRef), from which Mendeley gets all its information? 
This would also be helpful, when it comes to capitalization, umlauts, etc., because if I can't modify the bibtex code manually in Mendeley, it will be a pain to check the bibliography in the end again... 
it's like using Word again...

Thank's for any advice,
Best
Paul

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mendeley Desktop, supports importing *.bib files through `File->Import...->BibTex (.bib)`

[image]

A *.bib file is simply a plain text file - containing your BibTex code. So you can either open Notepad and past it there, then save it as your  pandalai.bib. Or you can export a bib file from JabRef and use that here directly.

Comment: I guess you can remove "on Windows", as this also works on mac (did not check linux, but I assume it would work too)

Comment: was about to post the same answer and had the image already uploaded - would be a shame to waste it :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, that'll do it!
(Even though I still think it's strange that there is no possibility to edit the tex-code within the program)